# Chrome no longer applies anti-aliasing to canvas

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

I really don't know where to start with this. I recently updated Chrome to 85.0.4183.102 and suddenly the game I was making keeps turning anti-aliasing for canvas on and off - mostly off.

I just have some 2D canvas-es that are drawn 20 times a second (really simple code) with the basic canvas geometric and image drawing functions. If I try an old backup of the game, the problem persists, so it must be something that changed in Chrome.

I asked to a friend and he says Chrome disables anti-aliasing when it's too busy, and I admit my code is so far from being efficient, but then the old backup should have no problems. Also, everything that happens in each frame requires only 2ms of the 50ms duration of each frame.

I really don't know where to start to solve this problem and I couldn't find anything on Google.

Comment: Do you have other tabs open or extensions running? Try disabling extensions and closing all tabs other than the one you are using for your game and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Just tried with no other tabs nor any enabled extension, still same problem.